# What does the dot dot dot mean in math?

Tags: notation, mathematical-physics, unitary-matrices, quantum-computation, quantum-information

Can someone please explain what the three dots mean?
I knew this at some point but I have memory issues so I have to relearn things a lot.

U (θ) = UL(θL) ··· U2(θ2)U1(θ1)

|ψ〉 = ]
φp ∈{φ}
aφ1···φη |φ1 · · · φi · · · φj · · · φη〉 = (−1)π
× ]
φp ∈{φ}
aφ1···φη |φ1 · · · φj · · · φi · · · φη〉

These equations are quantum computing equations. So it is using wavefunctions and Bra-Ket notation.

Comment: just to say there are some terms between

Comment: Generally it just means "the pattern continues in the obvious way." So for instance, 

$$a_1 \cdots a_9 \text{ means } a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5 a_6 a_7 a_8 a_9$$

Comment: The inticate a list of terms of which it'd be impossible to list them out individual (namely as we may not know how many there are).   For example if $13$ items $x_1,x_2, x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8,x_9, x_{10}, x_{11}, x_{12},x_{13}$ and I was asked to list them all I could do so.  But I probably wouldn't want to.  ANd if I said I have $n$ terms but I don't know how many $n$ is, and they are all indexed I *couldn't* write them all out.  So I'd list them as $x_1,x_2,......, x_n$ and assume it is clear that there are many more terms and it's clear how to fill in the gap.

Comment: Sometimes the 'three dots' **are** misused and don't mean anything correct, but, as others say, usually, when written by experts, they do mean something correct: the hard to write down missing part or gap. Still: theoretically you make a valid point. What do notationally three dots universally mean? Seems like they mean: "etc..." but perhaps deeper mathematics or logic needs  to be more specific in rigorous notation syntax/semantics

Answer (score 0):

I'll expand on the comments in an answer. As [PrincessEev](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/597568/princesseev) wrote, it generally means the pattern continues in the way one would expect.

In the first, the variable $L$ is decreasing by one each time. For example, if $L=5$, then

$$U(\theta) = U_5(\theta_5) U_4(\theta_4) U_3(\theta_3) U_2(\theta_2) U_1(\theta_1).$$

In the second expression, the dots are expressing that all the terms stay in their respective places, with the exception of the two terms $\varphi_i$ and $\varphi_j$. So maybe if $\eta = 5$, $i=2$, and $j=3$, then

- the term on the left would have a "$|\varphi_1\varphi_2\varphi_3\varphi_4\varphi_5\rangle$",
- whereas the term on the right would have a "$|\varphi_1\varphi_3\varphi_2\varphi_4\varphi_5\rangle$".

(I won't fully write out an example since I think your second formula isn't typed quite right in MathJax, but I suspect that you can fill in a similar example as I did above with $U(\theta)$.)